# Add results from several COUNT queries

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to fetch the sum of several counts in one query:

```
SELECT(
    SELECT COUNT( * )
    FROM comments +
    SELECT COUNT( * )
    FROM tags +
    SELECT COUNT( * )
    FROM search
)
```

I am missing something here. I get syntax error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments ) 
     + ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tags ) 
     + ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM search )
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Note: in Oracle, you have to add " from dual" to that syntax.

Answer (score 6):

One more (not sure if supported with MySQL, though - works in SQL Server):

```
SELECT SUM(Counts) FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counts FROM COMMENTS UNION ALL
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tags UNION ALL
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Search) s
```

Comment: Curious - what are the pros/cons of each of yours and the accepted answers' SQLs? Is one better in terms of performance? Something else?

Comment: To Liao: Run the query analyzer and see what it says. They may be synonymous.

Comment: Very nice. +1 for elegancy of SQL statement(s).

Comment: They should be the same; I like mine because it's far less typing. :D

Comment: @Matt: Ah, yes! A man after my own heart - lazy! <g> Mine comes from having to explain it to non-tech people all the time; the extra keystrokes lessen the verbiage of the explanation. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT (
       SELECT  COUNT(*)
       FROM    comments
       ) +
       (
       SELECT  COUNT(*)
       FROM    tags
       ) +
       (
       SELECT  COUNT(*)
       FROM    search
       )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(ThisCount)
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS ThisCount
      FROM comments

    UNION ALL

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS ThisCount
      FROM tags

    UNION ALL

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS ThisCount
      FROM search
    )
```

Comment: @ n8wrl: Beat you by a few minutes. <g> Besides dotjoe's catch, and just FYI, the column alias is only required in the first subselect, as it's ignored in the other three during the union operation.

Comment: @Ken: Thanks for that. What i was really after was the syntax that allowed me to refer to the first column in the sum() regardless of its name. NO joy.